# SQL Server Extended Events - How to filter statements by Table?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I am curious, is it possible to filter the SQL Statement by table (table id or something)?

[image]

What I can think of, is to naively add another 'Statement' with Operator 'like' '%MyTable%'. Is that any 'Field' to filter the Table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sql_statement_completed` event does not have an `object_id` or `object_name` field you can use to filter the events you are capturing.

It seems like you are trying to capture all the statements that change the data in one of your tables: you can capture that kind of information using the `lock_acquired` event and filtering for `IX` or `X` mode and the `object_id` you want to include.

Unfortunately, this will produce a large number of events, of which you probably want just one. You can overcome this problem by capturing the events in a histogram target or by streaming the events with the streaming API.

I blogged about something similar here: [Tracking Table Usage and Identifying Unused Objects](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/20/tracking-table-usage-and-identifying-unused-objects/).

Of course, if you're on Enterprise Edition, you can always use an [Audit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) for this purpose.

Hope this helps

Comment: Before everything, allow me to ask, is it this Extended Event is unable to capture the sql performed by an external program which runs LINQ?

Comment: It can capture anything, when set up correctly